# prevent the vector arrow from centering over the letter + subscript

Tags: amsmath, vector

I want to typeset a vector with an arrow over the top that has a long subscript. My approach makes the vector arrow center over the letter including its subscripts, but I want the arrow to be centered over the letter only instead. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this? I guess it will be kind of easy for you folks, but I couldn't find an answer by googling.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\(\Vec{H_{\mathrm{n,1}}}\)

\end{document}
```

my output:

[image]

I would like the vector arrow to be centered over the "H" instead of the whole thing.

Comment: `\(\Vec{H}_{\mathrm{n,1}}\)`

Comment: `\vec{H}_{n,1}` (I see no reason for `\mathrm`}. By the way, `\Vec` is exactly the same as `\vec`

Comment: I just realized the second I posted. I thought I had tried steven's approach before and it didn't work, but I must have screwed it up somehow. Thanks!

Comment: @egreg: \mathrm makes the subscripts upright instead of italic, it's just a requirement of my institution.

Comment: By the way, can I mark this closed somehow if there is no answer that I can accept? Can I accept comments as answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, using a vector notation with an upward slanting arrow positioned toward the center is not at all appealing to me. There are so many ways to write a vector in `LaTeX`. Here is a suggestion using [`esvect`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/esvect/esvect.pdf) package with the `c` option. But you can choose any of the options you like from the link that I have added.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[c]{esvect}

\begin{document}
\(\vv{H}_{n,1}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is with the option `f` similar to `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[f]{esvect}%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% option f. 

\begin{document}
\(\vv{H}_{n,1}\)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of the esvect package, these certainly look better than the arrows that \vec produces

Comment: @MS I am glad to have helped you.